# Conditional checks being skipped after 2nd iteration

Tags: python, csv, if-statement, while-loop

Python beginner here, would like to understand what is happening to my code snippet below? i am suppose to be reading from a CSV file and check the user's Input against the file. If user's input of Student ID exists within the CSV, the program will begin to print all existing information belonging to the Student ID.

The Contents of the CSV file are as follows

```
first_name,last_name,student_id,Math,Science,English,Art 
Peter,Tan,S1012342D,89,67,54,78
John,Lim,S1014322H,87,78,86,67
Ada,Ang,S1023456I,54,78,65,54
```

currently if i enter the correct ID on my first launch of the program, everything works correctly so far, all the outputs are coming out.
But when i purposely enter a wrong input & enter the correct input afterwards, it fails to read the correct input and my output of contents is not appearing.

Code I am working on is as follows
[image]
Would hope someone can point out what i am doing wrong or misunderstanding.

Comment: Please the actual code as text and not a picture.

Comment: python 3: you need to convert `value` to integer

Comment: sorry, but images of code are off topic. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`csv.DictReader` returns an iterator, so if you exhaust it by iterating through it, you will not be able to iterate through it again without resetting the file position.

Change:

```
if(check == False):
```

to:

```
if(check == False):
    csvfile.seek(0)
    next(reader) # skip the header
```

Comment: Yes it is working now, i had a hunch it was regarding my iterator pointing towards the end of the file but i didnt understood how it worked. Thanks!